# How to get current display mode in DirectX 11 including the refresh rate?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

How can I get the current display mode in DirectX 11, including the refresh rate.

In DX9 there was [GetAdapterDisplayMode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb174316(v=vs.85).aspx). As far as DX11 is concerned I can only see [DXGIOutput::GetDesc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174548(v=vs.85).aspx) but the [DXGI_OUPUT_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173068(v=vs.85).aspx) structure does not contain any information about refresh rate.

Comment: Well, DirectX 9 hasn't gone anywhere, so you could just use that. Otherwise this question address your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583294/how-to-get-current-display-mode-resolution-refresh-rate-of-a-monitor-output-i

Comment: I can't use DX9 because in DX9 refresh rates are treated as unsigned integers, in DX11 they are floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can call IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList() to get DXGI_MODE_DESC*.

Then, DXGI_MODE_DESC has RefreshRate member.

Comment: But how can I tell which DXGI_MODE_DESC is the correct one?

Comment: You can find the one that matches your desired(or desktop's) width/height. You can refer to this link. http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut03.html

Comment: In some cases there are multiple modes with the same resolution but different refresh rates.

Comment: You can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844654/how-to-find-out-real-screen-refresh-rate-not-the-rounded-number